# diff does not work with subdirectories

Tags: diff, patch

I want to patch whole directory tree. Although diff finds all differences, patch does apply these to relevant files. When I change a file in subdir I can see patch crate that file one level above it should in the directory tree being patched.

I use command:

```
diff -Nur extern/ local/ | patch -d extern
```

what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing -d *dir* ("Change to the directory dir immediately, before doing anything else.") you also need to tell patch to strip off one level of directories with -p:

```
diff -Nur extern/ local/ | patch -d extern -p1
```

That's because diff's output will look something like this:

```
+++  extern/foo.x
---  local/foo.x
@@ -21,7 +21,9 @@

- yyy
+ xxx
```

... so you need to get rid of that first prefix in the path.